# Material changing appearance when added to a layer

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I add a game object to a "highlight" layer, the purpose of which is to display additional information when the object is clicked on, it appears as if an additional material is added to the mesh renderer, even though there is no additional material there when I inspect the mesh renderer. The white color in the image is unintended.

[image]

I have a script that will add an additional material to a mesh renderer when looked at by the player. However, the effect in the image is not the same as the one caused by the script and is happening even when I open an empty scene and there is nothing in the scene except for a simple 3D shape in the highlight layer.

Is it possible for a script or something else to modify a gameobject when it is in a certain layer, even if it isn't present in the scene?